How to use Linux sed command to create this output?
I have a file with the name fks containing the following content:
ALTER TABLE "USER01"."TB01" ADD CONSTRAINT "TB01FK" FOREIGN KEY ("IDUSUARIO") REFERENCES "USER02"."TB02";

I need a script to produce this output based in my fks file content:
grant references on "USER02"."TB02" to "USER01";

Here is my current Bash script:
#!/bin/bash
# Read the 'fks' file line by line
cat fks | while read line; do
  # Extract the source schema (after "ALTER TABLE " and before the ".")
  schema_origin=$(echo $line | sed -E 's/ALTER TABLE "([^"]+)".*/\1/' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
  
  # Extract the referenced schema (after "REFERENCES " and before ".")
  schema_referenced=$(echo $line | sed -E 's/.*REFERENCES "([^"]+)".*/\1/')
  
  # Extract the referenced table name (after the last ".")
  table_referenced=$(echo $line | sed -E 's/.*\.([^"]+)".*/\1/')
  
  # Generate the GRANT statement with the referenced schema and table
  echo "grant references on \"$schema_referenced\".\"$table_referenced\" to \"$schema_origin\";"
done

However, the output is incorrect:
grant references on "USER02" to "USER01";

I need help correcting the script so that it correctly outputs the full referenced schema and table.

Why are you calling tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' in your code when your expected output doesn't contain any strings being converted to lower case?

(database) foreign key constraints can reference more than one column; if you know for a fact that all lines in fks will consist of single-column foreign key constraints then please state that; on the other hand, if fks may contain entries with multi-column foreign key constraints then please update the question with at least one such example

.*\.([^"]+)".* matches a period not followed by a double quote, while you want to match ."TABLE"...
Anyway, you don't need bash loops and several sed for this. One single sed run is enough to process each line of the file and to extract the different components:
sed -E 's/.*ALTER[[:space:]]+TABLE[[:space:]]+("[^"]*").*[[:space:]]+REFERENCES[[:space:]]+("[^"]*"[.]"[^"]*").*/grant references on \2 to \1;/i' fks

With GNU sed:
sed -E 's/.*ALTER\s+TABLE\s+("[^"]*").*\s+REFERENCES\s+("[^"]*"[.]"[^"]*").*/grant references on \2 to \1;/i' fks

If the ALTER TABLE part is always at the beginning of the line and the reference is always the last token we can simplify a bit:
sed -E 's/^[^"]*("[^"]*").*("[^"]*"[.]"[^"]*");$/grant references on \2 to \1;/i' fks

If you want a lower case output and your sed is GNU sed:
sed -E 's/^[^"]*("[^"]*").*("[^"]*"[.]"[^"]*");$/\Lgrant references on \2 to \1;/i' fks


Does the /i at the end of each script do anything? I thought it was to insert a subsequent string above the current line but there is no subsequent string in the scripts.

The i flag of the s command "Match the regular expression in a case-insensitive way". It used to be a GNU extension but is now POSIX (2024). For SQL queries it makes sense, I think. Note: for the 2 last scripts it is useless.

Huh, I thought that was I (upper case), not i (lower case), but I see in the latest POSIX spec you're right and I is just mentioned as "Note that some implementations of sed also support an I flag for the s command as an alias for the lower case i flag."

Ah, but there's also i<newline>text to insert text. Well, that's clear as mud - did sed really use all possible characters already so they have to overload them? Thanks for the info, I've only been using sed for 42 years, always an opportunity to learn something new apparently.

That's an important characteristic of sed: any command shall look as it had been obfuscated. Using the same character for completely different things is a nice obfuscation trick ;-). Note that the other s flags (g, p, w) are also command names...

Excellent observation :-). Pair that with "anything non-trivial requires a non-POSIX extension" and we have quite the loaded weapon.

You might find an awk script a bit easier to enhance and maintain, e.g. using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:
$ awk -F'"' '{printf "grant references on \"%s\".\"%s\" to \"%s\";\n", $(NF-3), $(NF-1), $2}' fks
grant references on "USER02"."TB02" to "USER01";

If you want USER01 converted to lower case as your code is attempting (but your expected output doesn't show), just tweak it to:
$ awk -F'"' '{printf "grant references on \"%s\".\"%s\" to \"%s\";\n", $(NF-3), $(NF-1), tolower($2)}' file
grant references on "USER02"."TB02" to "user01";


Assumptions:

OP's real file may contain multiple-column FOREIGN KEY clauses, eg, FOREIGN KEY ("COL1","COL2","COL3")

Setup:
$ cat fks
ALTER TABLE "USER01"."TB01" ADD CONSTRAINT "TB01FK" FOREIGN KEY ("IDUSUARIO") REFERENCES "USER02"."TB02";
ALTER TABLE "USER01"."TABLE_X" ADD CONSTRAINT "TB10FK" FOREIGN KEY ("COL1","COL2","COL3") REFERENCES "USER02"."TABLE_Y";

One idea where we allow read to parse a line of input based on the double quote (") as the delimiter, storing results in an array:
while IFS='"' read -ra arr
do
    # typeset -p arr                    # uncomment to display contents of array

    len="${#arr[@]}"
    printf 'grant references on "%s"."%s" to "%s";\n' "${arr[len-4]}" "${arr[len-2]}" "${arr[1]}"
done < fks

This generates:
grant references on "USER02"."TB02" to "USER01";
grant references on "USER02"."TABLE_Y" to "USER01";

